# Proving a set of linear maps is linearly independent technique

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

[image]

I am a bit confused as to what I have to show. I thought I needed to show that $\forall f \in P(R), x \in R$ if $a_1T_1 + ... + a_nT_n =0$ then all $a_i=0$ but the solution just applies $x^n$ to both sides. Why does this show that the linear maps are linearly independent?

Also why is this true in the first place? Does this not serve as an counter example?

If $n=3$ and $f(x)=x$ then $0*T_1(f(x)) + 4*T_2(f(x)) + 3*T_3(f(x)) = 0 +4*0 + 3*0 =0$ but not all $a_i$s are 0.

Comment: What's $\mathrm P( R)$?

Comment: set of all polynomials with coefficients in R (reals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not a counter-example. It just shows that $(0\times T_1+4T_2+3T_3)(x)=0$. So what? It would be a counter-example if $0\times T_1+4T_2+3T_3$ was the null function, but you have just proved that it takes the value $0$ at *some* $f(x)\in P(\Bbb R)$, not at *every* $f(x)$.

Anyway, suppose that$$a_1T_1+a_2T_2+\cdots+a_nT_n=0.$$Then$$(a_1T_1+a_2T_2+\cdots+a_nT_n)(x^n)=0,$$which means that $n!a_n=0$. So, $a_n=0$. So,\begin{align}0&=a_1T_1+a_2T_2+\cdots+a_nT_n\\&=a_1T_1+a_2T_2+\cdots+a_{n-1}nT_{n-1}.\end{align}But now the same argument shows that $a_{n-1}=0$ and so on.